# Waiting for AsyncTask to finish before destroying BroadcastReceiver Alarm

Tags: android, android-asynctask, broadcastreceiver

My Android application has some issues with the repeating alarm that I have set. The AsyncTask sometimes takes 5-15 seconds to complete, and in the upper ranges the task ends up not finishing because Android System ends up ending `onReceive` in the receiver class before the task completes.

Is there a way I can hold the alarm until the task completes, or is this bad practice?

Here is the `onReceive` of my intent class:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    getPrefs(context);
    color = (Color.parseColor("#FFFF4500"));
    instances = 0;

    backgroundExecute(context); //5-15 sec, sometimes doesn't get to finish

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I did some reading on the BroadcastReceiver documentation on Google's page, and found that using `goAsync()` in my onReceive would keep the broadcast alive until the result is returned by the AsyncTask.

Found here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#goAsync()